# Set ignore list for no-undef (Defining expected variables from other sources)

Tags: javascript, eslint, ecmascript-5

I've got some js code that, during tests gets loaded in multiple parts, and gets concatenated and uglified for prod.

I have a config file that defines a variable `myConfig` and have the business-logic script, that expects `myConfig` to be set and globally available.

This is working fine, and there are no errors during dev or prod.

The problem is that I'd like to use a `no-undef` eslint rule to catch other variables and function from missing declarations. So I'm looking for ways to define a set of expected variables.

Is there a way to define such variables?

Comment: If you are already packing and uglifying scripts, can't you just import your configuration script in your other scripts? Don't rely on global variables because that will only pollute the global namespace and make testing your code more difficult.

Comment: @Derek. I'm glad you can adhere to such nice absolutes in the projects you are creating. Some of us however don't have the luxury of creating projects from scratch and instead maintain legacy code. It's always refreshing to hear that the premise of the question is wrong rather than offering anything useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [rule documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef):

> Any reference to an undeclared variable causes a warning, unless the variable is explicitly mentioned in a `/*global ...*/` comment, or specified in the [`globals` key in the configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals). A common use case for these is if you intentionally use globals that are defined elsewhere (e.g. in a script sourced from HTML).

Further,

> ### Specifying Globals
>
> The no-undef rule will warn on variables that are accessed but not
>   defined within the same file. If you are using global variables inside
>   of a file then it’s worthwhile to define those globals so that ESLint
>   will not warn about their usage. You can define global variables
>   either using comments inside of a file or in the configuration file.
>
> To specify globals using a comment inside of your JavaScript file, use
>   the following format:
>
> ```
> /* global var1, var2 */
> ```
>
> This defines two global variables, var1 and var2. If you want to
>   optionally specify that these global variables should never be written
>   to (only read), then you can set each with a false flag:
>
> ```
> /* global var1:false, var2:false */
> ```
>
> To configure global variables inside of a configuration file, use the
>   `globals` key and indicate the global variables you want to use. Set
>   each global variable name equal to `true` to allow the variable to be
>   overwritten or `false` to disallow overwriting. For example:
>
> ```
> {
>     "globals": {
>         "var1": true,
>         "var2": false
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> And in YAML:
>
> ```
> ---
>   globals:
>     var1: true
>     var2: false
> ```
>
> These examples allow `var1` to be overwritten in your code, but
>   disallow it for `var2`.